# 2003 Chevy Cavalier (manual trani) stalls when coming to a stop after the car warms up

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, stall, cavalier

We have replaced the MAP sensor, the throttle position sensor and the fuel pump. None of these things made any difference. Also the problem is worse in warmer weather.

Comment: Try cleaning the Mass Air Flow (MAF) and Intake Air Temperature (IAT) sensors.

Comment: See if you have someone that will let you try swapping the coil pack, its a common place for things to go wrong its location in top of the engine.

Diagnostics will go a long way, test fuel pressure, check wiring to your CPS (Crank position sensor) on the front of these engine.

These car's do not have  MAF, they are pure Air Temperature and RPM fuel mapped cars. This car doesn't have a MAP on this car, you probably replaced the IAT.

On the stall?  Is it as soon as you release the throttle and push in the clutch, or once you've stopped completely?  Do the revs drop properly or do they hang?

Comment: The stall is when I push in the clutch. If I cannot give it gas soon enough it stalls. I'm not sure what you mean by "do they drop or hang", I can tell when we are going to stall as the RPMs go below 500

Comment: Also for some reason it stalls less often if the air conditioning is on??? strange

Comment: @Chris - You are right it doesn't appear to have a MAF. Every modern fuel injected car will have a MAF or MAP, with a lot of them having both. The Cavalier *absolutely* has a MAP sensor ([PN: 12614970](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=1490194&cc=1431632&jnid=506&jpid=7)). To the OP, I know what the issue is, it's just not coming to mind right now ... I'll see what I can do later to pull something up.

Comment: Next thing I'd check would be IAC Valve (Idle air controller) it can get gummed up, stuck or just die.  When you're not on the gas this is what keeps the car from stalling.

@Paulster2 that only applies for use in the super and turbocharged versions or with the upgrade kit. I've looked at the fuel tables on these cars and rebuilt 2 engines worth of them, there is no MAP I promise you. only temperature and RPM is used.  The ecotec was introduced in 2002, and until the G5 and Cobalt came along there was no MAP on the 2.2L engine.